# Enable Sessions in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am enabling Sessions in wordpress as follows.

Inside functions.php, I'm putting the following code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $user_ID;
$_SESSION['usuarioNome'] = $user_identity;
$_SESSION['email'] = $user_email;
$_SESSION['login'] = $user_login;

add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');

function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
```

But when logging in, it returns empty session variables.

Comment: I know I'm not running the code well, but I think this is the way to go. Can someone help me understand how I can get the sessions to work correctly in my wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that on each page you have

```
ob_start()
```

Comment: Think you'll need to provide OP more than that.

Comment: @idan noyshul I didn't understand. Can you explain better?

Comment: @@idan noyshul I think the problem is that when I redirect the login page, I immediately go to the page I created, which is https://xxxxxx/home.php and as it doesn't access any native wordpress page, it doesn't assign value to the variables session. But I don't see how to solve